# Legendre polynomials and formal groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, special-functions, formal-groups, legendre-polynomials

Let $P_n(x)$ be Legendre polynomials:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2tx+t^2}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(x)t^n.$$
Usual arguments from the theory of formal groups allow to
prove that for any $n$
$$P_n(x)=Q_n(P_1(x),P_2(x),P_4(x), \ldots,P_{2^k}(x),\ldots),$$
where $Q_n$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, depending on $P_{2^k}(x)$ such that $2^k\le n$. (Over $\mathbb Q$ every $P_n$ is a polynomial of $P_1$ and $P_2$.) For
example $$P_1=x,\quad P_2=\frac{1}{2}(3x^2-1),\quad
P_3=\frac{1}{2}(5x^3-3x)=P_1(3P_2-2P_1^2),$$ 
$$P_4=\frac{1}{8}(35x^4-30x^2+3),\quad
P_5=\frac{x}{8}(63x^4-70x^2+15)=P_1(5P_4+4P_1^2(P_1^2-5P_2)).$$
Here we have binary expasion in leading terms:
$$P_3=3P_2P_1+\ldots,\quad P_5=5P_4P_1+\ldots$$ Probably this property (existence of $Q_n$) is
known. Can you give any references concerning this fact?

For any $n$ the polynomial $Q_n$ is unique if (thanks to Victor Kleptsyn) we consider symbols $P_1$, $P_2$, $\ldots$ as coefficients of the formal group law. I don't know whether it is interesting to study properties of $Q_n$ but I'll be greatful for any additional information.

Comment: Would you be more precise on the form of $Q$? How does $Q$ depend on $n$? Which indices $2^j$ are to be considered?

Comment: I think that this is true for any  sequence of polynomials $(T_n)$, $\deg T_n=n$. In fact a more general statement seems to be true namely $x^n= Q_n(T_1(x),T_2(x),\dotsc, T_{2^k}(x),\dotsc)$, where $Q_n(t_1, t_2,\dotsc, t_{2k},\dotsc)$  is a polynomial.

Comment: That's why I'm asking. In that generality it's just binary expansion of $n$ and linear independence of monomials. Maybe the OP looks for an explicit $Q_n$?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: in the question it is mentioned that $Q$ should be a polynomial with \emph{integer}, not \emph{rational} coefficients. 
For instance, $P_4$ has a leading coefficient $1/8$, and I would say that you cannot represent it in such a way: given that the leading coefficient of $P_2$ is only $1/2$.
Alexey: I join Pietro Majer's question -- are you interested in any such $Q$, or should it have some other properties?

Comment: @Pietro Majer: yes, $Q$ depend on $n$

Comment: @Victor Kleptsyn:  the polynomial $Q_n$ is unique, I've made some corrections in my question.

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov: Thanks! But for the uniqueness, I suppose you are using some unpronounced properties of $Q$. For instance, the polynomials you are writing are homogenous (saying that the grading of a variable $P_k$ is set to~$k$). Otherwise, one can add $(2 P_2 -3P_1^2 +1)$, that is equal to zero.
But even assuming that $Q$ is homogenous, there are too many different terms for uniqueness: for instance, for degree 5 you might have $P_1$ times: $P_1^4$, $P_1^2 P_2$, $P_2^2$ and $P_4$, for a three-dimensional space (taking evenness into the account). Though, $P_2^2$ does not appear...

Comment: @Victor Kleptsyn: Victor, thank you, I've made some corrections.

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov: Alexey, thanks! But I'm afraid I'm not that used to formal group laws. May I ask what are the formal variables that are multiplied? (Should it be just one-dimensional x and y? Or is it a formal variable formed by all the $P_{2^n}$'s? Or?)
Second: if it does not require too much computations, may I ask for some more explicit $Q_i$'s? I'm interested in seeing which monomials will appear with nonzero coefficients -- for instance, for i=6,7,12,13...